# java shopping catalog for school

Tags: java

so i have to create a catalog for an assignment for school. the catalog has to take 3 products and store it in an array, then input the product code and the quantity of the product to give a price. entering "0" should end the program. before the program ends, it should print the total amount.

i cant get the total amount to print..it keeps giving me 0.0. what should i do?

this is my code

```
package catalog;


 import java.util.*;
 public class Catalog1 {
 private static final String[] products = new String[3];
 private static float total=0.0f; 
 private static final float tax = 15/100;
 private static final float[] subTotal = new float[3];
 private static final float[] itemTotal = new float[3];
 private static final double[]pPrice = new double[3];
 private static String pCode;
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        products[0] = "Condensed Milk"; 
         products[1] = "Distilled Water";
         products[2] = "Packed rice";
         pPrice[0] = (9.50);
         pPrice[1] = (3.00);
         pPrice[2] = (12.75);
        int quantity = 0;
        int orderNum = 0;
     Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);  



         do{ 
                System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("condensed Milk[M3487], $9.50 per can.");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Distilled Water [W3876], $3.00 a bottle.");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("packed Rice [R9983], $12.75 for 5lbs.");
                System.out.println("------------------------------------------");

                     System.out.println("Please enter order number (0 to stop)");
                                pCode = s.nextLine();

                                        if(pCode.equals("M3487")){
                                            System.out.println("condensed Milk $9.50");
                                                System.out.println("Enter Quantity");
                                                    quantity = s.nextInt();
                                                       itemTotal[0] = (float) (pPrice[0]*quantity); 
                                                        System.out.println(quantity + " condensed Milk @ $9.50 = $" + itemTotal[0]);

                                        }else if(pCode.equals("W3876")){
                                             System.out.println("Distilled Water $3.00");
                                                System.out.println("Enter Quantity");
                                                    quantity = s.nextInt();
                                                        itemTotal[1] = (float) (pPrice[1] * quantity);
                                                        System.out.println(quantity +" Distilled Water @ 3.00 = $" + itemTotal[1]);

                                        }else if(pCode.equals("R9983")){
                                             System.out.println("packed Rice $12.75");
                                               System.out.println("Enter Quantity");
                                                   quantity = s.nextInt();
                                                        itemTotal[2] = (float) (pPrice[2] * quantity);
                                                        System.out.println(quantity +" Distilled Water @ 3.00 = $" + itemTotal[2]);

                                            }else if(pCode.equals("0")){
                                                System.out.println("your total bill is $" + total);
                                                break;
                                            }//close if statement
                                        orderNum++;
                                        quantity++;


            }while(true);//close while loop

}//close main method

public static float totalBill() {


           subTotal[0] = itemTotal[0] * tax;
           subTotal[1] = itemTotal[1] * tax;
           subTotal[2] = itemTotal[2] * tax;
           total = subTotal[0] + subTotal[1] + subTotal[2] + itemTotal[0] +     itemTotal[1] + itemTotal[2];
    return total ; 

}//close bill method
    }//close class
```

the output shows this

---

condensed Milk[M3487], $9.50 per can.

Distilled Water [W3876], $3.00 a bottle.

packed Rice [R9983], $12.75 for 5lbs.

---

Please enter order number (0 to stop)
M3487
condensed Milk $9.50
Enter Quantity
2
2 condensed Milk @ $9.50 = $19.0

---

condensed Milk[M3487], $9.50 per can.

Distilled Water [W3876], $3.00 a bottle.

packed Rice [R9983], $12.75 for 5lbs.

---

Please enter order number (0 to stop)

---

condensed Milk[M3487], $9.50 per can.

Distilled Water [W3876], $3.00 a bottle.

packed Rice [R9983], $12.75 for 5lbs.

---

Please enter order number (0 to stop)

Comment: You have a method to calculate the total bill, but you don't use it.  There also seems to be some confusion regarding scope. You don't need to update an instance variable _and_ return it. The "regular" way would be to not have an instance variable, and possibly arguments.

Comment: Also you're performing integer division here: `private static final float tax = 15/100;`. When you fixed those two things maybe you'll have your expected results.

Comment: how do i call it?. i'm trying, but nothing i do is working.

Comment: `System.out.println("your total bill is $" + totalBill());`

Comment: You should find a tutorial on basic java. To call the function you'd use `totalBill()`. But be sure to understand return values, parameters and arguments before you start calling functions.

Comment: Why you are incrementing the quantity variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To paraphrase the comments:

```
private static final float tax = 0.15f;
```

and

```
System.out.println("your total bill is $" + totalBill());
```

Comment: this fixes the problem, however i encountered another problem. after i entered the product code and quantity, the menu appears twice.

Comment: Do you mean it appears again? That's because it is inside the do-while loop.

Comment: i want it to appear again, that's why i put it in the loop, but it appears twice instead of once.

Comment: Have tried stepping through your code using a debugger?

Comment: yeah, debugger didn't find anything.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the output to the screen for your test run.

Comment: i edited it to show the output that i'm getting, the menu shows up twice after the input of the product code and quantity.

Comment: I would suggest adding a final `else` where you have `}//close if statement` to print out any unrecognised entry.

Comment: i changed the if statements into a switch, but i'm still having the same problem.